# Using Scanner object to read series of inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to retrieve three inputs an integer, a string and a double; here is how I thought i would do [*Note:The String containing a space*]

```
record.setAccountNumber(input.nextInt());
record.setName(input.nextLine());
record.setBalance(input.nextDouble());
```

I tried to replace input.nextLine() in

```
record.setName(input.nextLine());
```

with input input.next(), because of an InputMisMatchException but still the problem is not resolved. the error is thrown because a double value is probably assigned to a new line value[this is what I think not sure] is there a way to retrieve the string containing a space and be able to finish the three inputs I have to enter at the same time.  thanks

NOTE: I couldn't find any relating problem to this one 
Let me just add the whole method within which the error occurs

```
public void addAccountRecords(){
    AccountRecord record = new AccountRecord();
    input = new Scanner (System.in);

    try {
        output = new Formatter("oldmast.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating or opening the file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (SecurityException e){
        System.err.println("No write access to this file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }


    System.out.println("Enter respectively an account number\n"+
            "a name of owner\n"+"the balance");

        while ( input.hasNext()){
            try{
                record.setAccountNumber(input.nextInt());
                record.setName(input.nextLine());
                record.setBalance(input.nextDouble());

                if (record.getBalance() >0){
                    output.format("%d\t%s\t%,.2f%n",record.getAccountNumber(),
                            record.getName(),record.getBalance());
                    record.setCount((record.getCount()+1));
                }else
                    System.err.println("The balance should be greater than zero");

            }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                System.err.println("Invalid input, please try again");
                e.printStackTrace();
                input.nextLine();

            }catch (FormatterClosedException e){
                System.err.println("Error writing to File");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter respectively an account number\n"+
                    "a name of owner\n"+"the balance\n or End of file marker <ctrl> z");
        }//end while
        output.close();
        input.close();

}//end AddAccountRecords
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextLine` will read all the remaining data to the end of your string, including the double. You need to use `next` instead. I'm not sure why you get an `InputMisMatchException` - this works for example:

```
String s = "123 asd 123.2";
Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
System.out.println(input.nextInt());    //123
System.out.println(input.next());       //asd
System.out.println(input.nextDouble()); //123.2
```

So the issue is possibly in your input or somewhere else in your code.

Notes:

- If I use `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` and enter `123 asd 123.2` I get the same result.
- if the string (second entry) contains spaces, the second word will be parsed as double and will generate the error your report

Comment: yeah sure that works but instead of using asd try to use [as d] with a space, am not sure if it's gonna work.

Comment: @RuruMorlano That is my second note. If you have a space in the middle, you should ask the int, string and double separately (i.e. on separate lines).